# Unity accessing variables from another script performance

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

Option 1:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour{
    Data _data;
    float speed;

    void Awake(){
        speed = _data.speed;
    }

    void Update(){
        Move(speed);
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour{
    Data _data;

    void Update(){
        Move(_data.speed);
    }
}
```

Is there any performance difference between these two using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends largely if `speed` in the `Data` class is a property with some code execution or just a normal field.

not much of a difference:

```
public float speed = 2f;
```

has an impact on performance:

```
public float speed {
    get {
         return ExpensiveFunction();
    }
}
```